# Apparently Some non standard Characters are seen as regular Characters

Tags: javascript, text, utf-8

I make an intentional error using a character that seems nonstandard but is availiable to use:

```
var ᛨ={};
ᛨ.causeError()

Uncaught TypeError: è.causeError is not a function
```

Apparently ᛨ character is a version of è character

(a utf-8 normal text character a,b,c is text)

vs

(non text ☎,®,෴,%)

è === http://unicode-table.com/en/00E8/

```
Encoding      hex             dec (bytes)    dec            binary
UTF-8         C3 A8           195 168        50088          11000011 10101000
UTF-16BE      00 E8           0 232          232            00000000 11101000
UTF-16LE      E8 00           232 0          59392          11101000 00000000
UTF-32BE      00 00 00 E8     0 0 0 232      232            00000000 00000000 00000000 11101000
UTF-32LE      E8 00 00 00     232 0 0 0      3892314112     11101000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

ᛨ === http://unicode-table.com/en/16E8/

```
Encoding      hex            dec (bytes)     dec            binary
UTF-8         E1 9B A8       225 155 168     14785448       11100001 10011011 10101000
UTF-16BE      16 E8          22 232          5864           00010110 11101000
UTF-16LE      E8 16          232 22          59414          11101000 00010110
UTF-32BE      00 00 16 E8    0 0 22 232      5864           00000000 00000000 00010110 11101000
UTF-32LE      E8 16 00 00    232 22 0 0      3893755904     11101000 00010110 00000000 00000000
```

I don't see the correlation!

How can I test non-standard characters to see if they have a correlation with a normal text character?

What is the relation I would look for?

Out of interest; Is this Unicode issue documented anywhere?

**[This question, after further thought, isn't completely solved (see comments)]**

Comment: I don't really see a case where it should matter, but that's quite an interesting issue :)

Comment: Yes I think its very interesting!

Comment: Also, I just checked. You can still make a property called ᛨ and another called "è". It seems to be just an issue with the console output for the error.

Comment: Maybe but, then why would the console relate the two?

Comment: Well, the obvious connection is that the second byte of 16E8 is E8, so if it was misinterpreted as a pair of single-byte characters, you'd see an è

Comment: Incidentally, as far as Unicode's concerned there's nothing more "normal" about an accented Latin character than an Icelandic Runic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tested with a variable called ಠ_ಠ, the error message contains " _ " (space underscore space). It looks like the code that writes error messages doesn't support as many characters as it should.

The same issue happens in the console, so it's not a file encoding problem. Plus the characters are managed without any issue EXCEPT in automated error messages. Even writing `throw new Error("ಠ_ಠ");` works without a problem.

That seems like a rather specific bug, but it affects both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I would say that my original question is null and void (though interesting)

Comment: If anyone else has further insight, be my guest!

Answer (score 1):

`è` 'coincidentally' is character `E8` in western ANSI encodings, which is also the second byte of the UTF-16 code point for your special character (and `è in UTF-16 too, by the way).

If you are working from a source file: You may have saved your file in the wrong encoding, maybe in ANSI, probably in UTF-16. Make sure your source file is saved in the right encoding. The 'right' encoding can be just about anything (although UTF-8 is recommended), as long as it matches the Content-Encoding headers you send with your file and it can contain every character you want to put in it.

If you are working from the console: If it's just the console messing up, this still explains the issue. Internally, the browser will probably use a different encoding than UTF-8, because UTF-8 is efficient for transmission, but not convenient to work with. Most likely it uses UTF-16 (or UCS2). Your character would then be encoded in a double byte code point `16 E8`. If the console tries to display each byte as separate characters, it will show `E8` as `'è'` and skip `16` altogether, since it is historically an ASCII control character (SYN, for Synchronous Idle) and not intended for display at all.

Comment: There is no file I am only playing with the console on a normal Chrome browser. I think we are close to the answer though (+1). Maybe the real question is why is a skip to the second byte of UTF-16 happening (and ok)?

Comment: See the last paragraph. The console probably displays the symbol as two (ANSI) characters, but the first one, 16, is historically a control character and cannot be displayed by the console.

Comment: In fact that last paragraph is quite knowlegable

Comment: Yes, I hope so. I don't know a solution, though. I can't find a way to set or correct his. On the other hand, if you input it correctly, maybe the browser should handle it correctly too. Based on the information I have so far, I'd say this might be a bug.

Comment: **Well, thinking more about this: I still consider this open. Ok, so we've established that the console is not as equipped to display these 'extra' characters, yet the question still begs why do they slip though un-noticed whereas other seemingly similar characters will properly cause error?**

Comment: Because the actual JavaScript runtime does handle the multi-byte characters properly. So internally, the browser knows that the variable is actually called with the (valid) name 'ᛨ'. If you use a character that is actually illegal, like `€`, you get a different error: "Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

Comment: As a bonus, here's a site that checks if a character is allowed in a variable name: https://mothereff.in/js-variables

Comment: An example of Unexpected ILLEGAL token can be found in the same alphabet as ᛨ at http://unicode-table.com/en/16F8/ (Runic). It shows as ᛸ. Why is ᛨ failing to cause error, but  ᛸ succeeds?

Comment: I think you pasted something wrong. If I try `ᛸ = {}; ᛸ.test();` (with `ᛸ` copied from the page you linked), I get the same type of error: "ø.test is not a function". ø happens to be the Ansi character F8, 'Latin small letter o with slash', so the behavior is the same as with the other rune. Or maybe there is a difference in implementation between browsers. I'm using Chrome.